# Software Implementing Jiles-Atherton

Tags: nonlinear-programming

I have been doing much research on the internet to see if there was a FEM simulator that natively implemented the Jiles-Artherton model whether it be commercial or open source

So far, my conclusion is that there is none. Before I make a final verdict though, I would like to check with the community that this statement is correct. Is there any software package that natively implements the Jiles-Artherton model?

I am looking into this because I am working on finding a focal point to my PhD thesis research and I was thinking about creating a simulator for non-linear magnetic simulations. It would include a number of different features such as SPICE simulation that couples with the FEA simulation and parallel computing (both SPICE and FEA simulation). This would also include implementing a Jiles-Artherton model natively into the software.

I am though concerned that my project is not too much on the researchy side of things and worried this may not be funded since alot of the commercial software packages implement what I would like to do. So, I would also like to ask the community for some feedback, if possible, on the current research topic. Everything is still in an incubation since I start in the coming spring semester. I am asking this because both my professor and I are relatively new to the field.

Comment: Despite 18 years of finite element experience, I've never heard the term "Jiles Atherton". I suspect that is the case for most other potential readers here. Can you update your question by stating in formulas what that model is or does?

Comment: There are a number of hysteresis models in commercial codes (for ferromagnetic magnetostatics at least) that may be isomorphic to Jiles-Atherton.  Have you looked at AnSoft's Maxwell 2D and 3D?

Comment: Hello Wolfgang, I have only recently started in the area so I do not have formulas at this time. However, I do have the concept. The idea behind the Jiles-Artherton model is that it is an "accurate" model for simulating a magnetic material's hysteresis curve. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jiles-Atherton_model

Comment: Hello Biswajit, I have looked at different commercial software; however, I could not find if they specifically used the Jiles-Artherton model in their simulations

Comment: Here's a response from an expert who works at a leading software vendor: "I am not 100% certain but it seems that CST and JMAG do not have native support for this model but Ansys does.

However, JMAG's implementation could be more generic that let's one plug and play different hysteresis model.

Solving this model amounts to just solving an ODE and could be pre-computed with MATLAB if desired."

Comment: Hello Biswajit, Thank you for the information! I did not know this, thank you

Comment: You can try open-source implementation in Matlab / Octave [https://github.com/romanszewczyk/JAmodel](https://github.com/romanszewczyk/JAmodel)